# Rational map from a smooth surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know that a rational map $f$ from a smooth variety $X$ to a projective variety $Y$ must be defined away from a set of codimension at least 2. So if $X$ is a surface, it is defined everywhere but finitely many points. I know that the inverse of a blowup provides an example of a rational map between surfaces which fails to be defined everywhere. My question is, what if $X$ is a surface, but the image of $f$ is one-dimensional? Then can we conclude that $f$ is defined everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The following rational map for example is not defined at $(0:0:1)$   $$\mathbb P^2\to \mathbb P^1:(x:y:z)\mapsto (x:y)$$